# как строку распарсить на 3 переменные разделенные между собой точкой

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, парсер, asp.net

У меня со считывателя штрихкодов приходит строка, в которой заложено 3 необходимых мне переменных. Они разделены точкой. Как мне записать их в переменные с помощью регулярки? т.е. я так понимаю, что нужно поместить мою строку в шаблон, после, при совпадении обращаемся к именованным группам, берем их значения и парсим в число.

Только вот в регулярках я не силен от слова совсем. `(?'value3'\d+)` допустим вот эта часть выделяет выражение в именованную группу для чисел как я понял. а для строки будет тоже самое только без `\d+` ????

Comment: зачем регулярки? Чем обычный Split по точке не устроил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем в данном случае регулярному выражению знать где число, а где строка, если есть конкретный разделитель - точка, вот его и надо использовать:

```
@"([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.([^.]*)"
```

Первая, вторая и третья группы, состоящие из "не точек", разделённые между собой точками.
Или же порядок переменных в строке точно не определён?

Группа в регулярном выражении выделятся скобками `()`. А обращаться к группам можно по порядковому номеру.
Пример:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.([^.]*)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("abcde.01234.абвгд");
var var0 = matches[0].Groups[0];
var var1 = matches[0].Groups[1];
var var2 = matches[0].Groups[2];
var var3 = matches[0].Groups[3];
```

Comment: Разделю получается эти переменные, а обратиться к ним как, чтобы записать их в переменные?

Comment: @Sosiska Добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Answer (score 3):

как вариант без регулярок

```
var str = "123.abc.123abc";
var splitted = str.Split('.');

Console.WriteLine(splitted[0]);
Console.WriteLine(splitted[1]);
Console.WriteLine(splitted[2]);
```

Вывод

```
123
abc
123abc
```